# Why are my mesh edits reverted?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

I've received a model from someone else. Any changes I make to the mesh in *Edit Mode* seem to be undone when I return to *Object Mode*.

On the left is the mesh in *Edit Mode*, on the right is the same mesh in *Object Mode*:

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try going through the following checklist:

- Check to see if the problem might be caused by Modifiers.
- Try turning off or deleting Shape Keys on the Object Data tab.
- Clear out any Keyframes
- Clear displacement and rotation of bones
- Try removing the armature from the object